# Returning white page?

Tags: php, image, api, gd

I have built somekinda image-api-key for my website but it doesn't seem to work. I get an blank page, returning nothing! Whats wrong? Greetings.

```
if(isset($_GET['key']) && !empty($_GET['key'])){
    $query = "  SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    table
                WHERE
                    apikey = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key']) ."'
    ";
    $mysqlquery = mysql_query($query);

    if($mysqlquery){

        if(mysql_num_rows($mysqlquery) > 0){

            if(isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['image'])){


                if($_GET['type'] == "gif"){


                    if($_GET['image'] == "1"){
                        header('Content-type: image/gif');
                        echo file_get_contents('path/to/image/1.gif');
                    }

                    elseif($_GET['image'] == "2"){
                        header('Content-type: image/gif');
                        echo file_get_contents('path/to/image/2.gif');
                    }

                    elseif($_GET['image'] == "3"){
                        header('Content-type: image/gif');
                        echo file_get_contents('path/to/image/3.gif');
                    }

                    elseif($_GET['image'] == "4"){
                        header('Content-type: image/gif');
                        echo file_get_contents('path/to/image/4.gif');
                    }

                    elseif($_GET['image'] == "5"){
                        header('Content-type: image/gif');
                        echo file_get_contents('path/to/image/5.gif');
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        die('Could not load image');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    die('Could not load image');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                die('Could not load image');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            die('Api key was not correct');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die('Mysql query failed');
    }
}
else
{
    die('No api key was set');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the headers have not already been sent? Try echoing `intval(headers_sent())` just before you cal the `header()` function. Because this could cause an error which would result in a blank screen.

Comment: @Petah Its returning `0` so i think its false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your error logs/ensure you have logging turned on as it sounds very much like PHP is throwing an error. (N.B.: If this is a production environment, be sure to turn logging back off afterwards.)

At a guess if could be one of the paths that's incorrect or you've already output some data prior to attempting to set a header, but the error logs should make it pretty obvious what the problem is.

Comment: Well i don't get any errors in the apache logs... And when i remove the `header('Content-type')` i get the code of the image but not the image itself...

Comment: @Thew In that case, it's possible the image data is being corrupted. You could try adding an `exit` after each of the calls to file_get_contents. (Unless of course you're intentionally continuing to execute the script for some reason.)

Comment: @middaparka Well i still get nothing... But this problem came after i added the query, can that block anything of the image?

Comment: @Thew The SQL query should't make any odds. I think you probably just need to step through the logic line by line, echoing the variables as you go. (Incidentally, using a [switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) on the $_GET['image'] would be a lot neater than the if/elseif construction.)

Comment: @middaparka Well when i echo $mysqlquery i get `Resource id #5`...?

Comment: @Thew That's fine - mysql_query returns a link identifier resource.

Comment: @middaparka Okay but what is the problem then? And switch is quite usefull, thanks for that =)

Comment: Make sure nothing else is being echoed or outputted to the page. This includes making sure there is no whitespace inbetween any of your `<?php` or `?>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is throwing certain kinds of errors such as syntax errors it will output an error message and terminate without any other output.  However, if display_errors is turned off in php.ini then not even the error message will be output and you'll just get a blank screen.

Alternatively, if you're trying to send a file that doesn't exist after you've sent the image/gif header then this could also result in a blank page.  Look at the headers that got sent back.  If you got an image/gif content type header back then the code is reaching a point where it's trying to send an image.  The fact you don't actually get an image would suggest that there's no image file to send.